# How to reinitialize HammerJS on resize event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize, hammer.js

How do I reinitialize HammerJS on resize event?

My problem is when I trigger the resize event the Selectors reset, and using jQuery for matching a container $('.container') will return an index of 0 all the time.. on document ready it worked before.

The $('.container') appears more than once so it should increment on swipe event.

Anyone got any ideas ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    mobileCalculus(animation);
    swipeActions( $('.home-element-wrapper'), $('.home').width());

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        mobileCalculus(animation);
    });
});


function swipeActions(parent, offset) {
    var curInd = 0;
    var theThumb = $('.thumb');
    var myElement = document.getElementById('main-swipe');
    var max = theThumb.length - 1;

    // create a simple instance
    // by default, it only adds horizontal recognizers
    var mc = new Hammer(myElement);

    // listen to events...
    mc.on("swipeleft", function(ev) {

        curInd = $('.thumb.active').index() + 1;
        if (curInd > max) {
            curInd = max;
        }
        var newML = offset * curInd;
        theThumb.removeClass('active');
        theThumb.eq(curInd).addClass('active');
        console.log($('.thumb.active').index() + 1);
        parent.css({
            'margin-left': '-'+newML+'px'
        });
    });
    mc.on("swiperight", function(ev) {
        curInd = $('.thumb.active').index() - 1;
        if (curInd < 0) {
            curInd = 0;
        }
        var newML = offset * curInd;
        theThumb.removeClass('active');
        theThumb.eq(curInd).addClass('active');
        parent.css({
            'margin-left': '-'+newML+'px'
        });
    });

}
```

For example jquery has a function called `.off` which deactivates the event after which we can put a new event on the selector.

```
$('element').off('swiperight').on('swiperight')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I've figured it out. I had to make the `var mc = new Hammer(myElement);` value "global". Apparently when I reinitialized it the second time in `swipeActions()`, the `off()` function would not work, so initializing the value only once and then performing `off()` and `on()` with it makes everything work.